# mac terminal displaying other name than host name

Tags: terminal

I have recently been in terminal and somehow I lost my Mac name.  It's showing a strange IP followed by some numbers.  My computer's name is "my-xxx-macbook-pro."  When I type `hostname` I receive:

ip-10-xx-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal

I have been working in AWS a lot to try to develop some products.

How do I get back to my computer in terminal?

Comment: Thanks @Allan for keeping me honest! :) I've retracted the close vote.

Comment: We seem to have multiple questions that could be duplicates, should probably decide on one best one.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere, whether it be in a virtual network created in AWS or your company's own network, you are being assigned a hostname through a DHCP server (and possibly in conjunction with a RADIUS server).

Looking at the format of the assigned name, it's too specific (us-west-2.compute.internal), and the IP address and domain both point to *internal* networks.

You can manually set your hostname with the command:

`sudo scutil --set HostName "YourHostName"`

However, when you reboot, it will revert back to whatever has been assigned to you.  Your best bet is to check with your network manager.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this but this is my personal laptop and this is on my home network.  There is no network manager.  Is there a way to log out and log into my Mac?  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?